# SQL Server: tools to show relations

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, view

I have an access to SQL Server database to query data using views (I don't have access to tables). I don't have a description about the views. What tools can I use to view dependenices and relations between views (common id columns, 1-N relations etc.)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's some great tools from Atlantis UK which are now free, including [Schema Surf](http://www.atlantis-interactive.co.uk/products/schemasurf/default.aspx). Check it out.

Comment: Thanks, does it understand relations based on column names (in views), not just PK-FK relations on tables?

Comment: @atricapilla - I'd be surprised if it does, but give it a whirl to be sure